# Android Project on image inpainting

Tags: java, android, image-processing

i want to develop a method which takes in an image input and gives the inpainted image of the green regions in the image.
So till now I have made an android program which allows the user to color the area or region to be inpainted to green and next I want to apply the inpaint method to this greenish region. I have gone through many java source code of image inpaint one of which I am posting here but in this it uses java libraries.Now I want to use the same method in android.
I want to develop an android project which on finger motion on screen creates a small patch and then changes that patch to its neighbouring pixel and returns the updated image..So this way the object on which you are using motion event hides off and its background gets copied in its place. 
Here is the java code:

```
/*     */ package inpaint;
/*     */ 
/*     */ import imageselection.Main;
/*     */ import java.awt.Image;
/*     */ import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
/*     */ import java.awt.image.PixelGrabber;
/*     */ import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
/*     */ import java.io.PrintStream;
/*     */ import java.util.Vector;
/*     */ import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
/*     */ 
/*     */ public class ImageInpaint
/*     */ {
/*     */   BufferedImage origImg;
/*     */   Image fillImg;
/*     */   BufferedImage img;
/*     */   WritableRaster raster;
/*     */   int iw;
/*     */   int ih;
/*     */   int[] pixels;
/*     */   int[][] pixelmap;
/*     */   int[][] fillPixelmap;
/*     */   int[][] sourceRegion;
/*     */   int[][] initialSourceRegion;
/*     */   double[][] fillRegion;
/*     */   double[][] gradientX;
/*     */   double[][] gradientY;
/*     */   double[][] confidence;
/*     */   double[][] data;
/*     */   GradientCalculator gc;
/*  57 */   double omega = 0.7D;
/*  58 */   double Alpha = 0.2D;
/*  59 */   double Beta = 0.8D;
/*     */   int maxX;
/*     */   int maxY;
/*     */   int minX;
/*     */   int minY;
/*  64 */   int continuousCol = 0;
/*  65 */   int continuousRow = 0;
/*     */   protected Main owner;
/*  67 */   public Boolean halt = Boolean.valueOf(false);
/*  68 */   public Boolean completed = Boolean.valueOf(false);
/*  69 */   final int diamX = 50;
/*  70 */   final int diamY = 30;
/*     */   private int pixelPosX;
/*     */   private int pixelPosY;
/*  73 */   int w = 3;
/*  74 */   double[][] con = { { 1.0D, 1.0D, 1.0D }, { 1.0D, -8.0D, 1.0D }, { 1.0D, 1.0D, 1.0D } };
/*     */   
/*     */   public ImageInpaint(Main owner)
/*     */   {
/*  81 */     this.owner = owner;
/*     */   }
/*     */   
/*     */   public void init(BufferedImage a_origImg, BufferedImage a_fillImg, Boolean quickInpaint)
/*     */   {
/*  93 */     this.halt = Boolean.valueOf(false);
/*     */     try
/*     */     {
/*  96 */       this.origImg = a_origImg;
/*  97 */       this.img = a_origImg;
/*  98 */       this.fillImg = a_fillImg;
/*  99 */       this.raster = this.origImg.getRaster();
/*     */       
/* 101 */       this.iw = this.img.getWidth(null);
/* 102 */       this.ih = this.img.getHeight(null);
/*     */       
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 107 */       this.pixels = new int[this.iw * this.ih];
/* 108 */       PixelGrabber pg = new PixelGrabber(this.img, 0, 0, this.iw, this.ih, this.pixels, 0, this.iw);
/* 109 */       pg.grabPixels();
/* 110 */       this.pixelmap = new int[this.ih][this.iw];
/* 112 */       for (i = 0; i < this.ih; i++) {
/* 113 */         for (int j = 0; j < this.iw; j++) {
/* 114 */           this.pixelmap[i][j] = this.pixels[(i * this.iw + j)];
/*     */         }
/*     */       }
/* 121 */       PixelGrabber fillPg = new PixelGrabber(this.fillImg, 0, 0, this.iw, this.ih, this.pixels, 0, this.iw);
/* 122 */       fillPg.grabPixels();
/* 123 */       this.fillPixelmap = new int[this.ih][this.iw];
/* 125 */       for (i = 0; i < this.ih; i++) {
/* 126 */         for (int j = 0; j < this.iw; j++) {
/* 127 */           this.fillPixelmap[i][j] = this.pixels[(i * this.iw + j)];
/*     */         }
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/*     */     catch (InterruptedException e1)
/*     */     {
/* 132 */       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this.owner, "Error " + e1, "Error!!", 0);
/*     */       
/* 134 */       System.out.println("Error " + e1);
/*     */     }
/* 140 */     this.gc = new GradientCalculator();
/* 141 */     this.gc.calculateGradientFromImage(this.pixelmap, this.ih, this.iw);
/* 142 */     this.gradientX = this.gc.gradientX;
/* 143 */     this.gradientY = this.gc.gradientY;
/*     */     
/* 145 */     initialize_confidence_term();
/* 146 */     initialize_data_term();
/*     */     
/* 148 */     this.fillRegion = new double[this.ih][this.iw];
/* 149 */     this.sourceRegion = new int[this.ih][this.iw];
/* 150 */     this.initialSourceRegion = new int[this.ih][this.iw];
/*     */     
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 155 */     this.minX = this.iw;
/* 156 */     this.minY = this.ih;
/* 157 */     this.maxX = (this.maxY = 0);
/*     */     
/*     */ 
/* 160 */     this.continuousRow = (this.continuousCol = 0);
/* 161 */     for (int i = 0; i < this.ih; i++)
/*     */     {
/* 162 */       int countrow = 0;
/* 163 */       for (int j = 0; j < this.iw; j++)
/*     */       {
/* 164 */         int pixel = this.fillPixelmap[i][j];
/* 165 */         int r = 0xFF & pixel >> 16;
/* 166 */         int g = 0xFF & pixel >> 8;
/* 167 */         int b = 0xFF & pixel;
/* 172 */         if ((r == 0) && (g == 255) && (b == 0))
/*     */         {
/* 173 */           countrow++;
/* 174 */           this.fillRegion[i][j] = 1.0D;
/* 175 */           this.sourceRegion[i][j] = 0;
/* 176 */           this.initialSourceRegion[i][j] = 0;
/* 177 */           if (j < this.minX) {
/* 178 */             this.minX = j;
/*     */           }
/* 180 */           if (i < this.minY) {
/* 181 */             this.minY = i;
/*     */           }
/* 183 */           if (j > this.maxX) {
/* 184 */             this.maxX = j;
/*     */           }
/* 186 */           if (i > this.maxY) {
/* 187 */             this.maxY = i;
/*     */           }
/*     */         }
/*     */         else
/*     */         {
/* 190 */           if (countrow > this.continuousRow) {
/* 191 */             this.continuousRow = countrow;
/*     */           }
/* 193 */           countrow = 0;
/* 194 */           this.fillRegion[i][j] = 0.0D;
/* 195 */           this.sourceRegion[i][j] = 1;
/* 196 */           this.initialSourceRegion[i][j] = 1;
/*     */         }
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/* 201 */     for (i = 0; i < this.iw; i++)
/*     */     {
/* 202 */       int countcol = 0;
/* 203 */       for (int j = 0; j < this.ih; j++)
/*     */       {
/* 204 */         int pixel = this.fillPixelmap[j][i];
/* 205 */         int r = 0xFF & pixel >> 16;
/* 206 */         int g = 0xFF & pixel >> 8;
/* 207 */         int b = 0xFF & pixel;
/* 211 */         if ((r == 0) && (g == 255) && (b == 0))
/*     */         {
/* 212 */           countcol++;
/*     */         }
/*     */         else
/*     */         {
/* 214 */           if (countcol > this.continuousCol) {
/* 215 */             this.continuousCol = countcol;
/*     */           }
/* 217 */           countcol = 0;
/*     */         }
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/* 225 */     Boolean flag = Boolean.valueOf(true);
/*     */     
/* 227 */     double[][] temp = new double[this.ih][this.iw];
/* 228 */     double[][] sourceGradX = new double[this.ih][this.iw];
/* 229 */     double[][] sourceGradY = new double[this.ih][this.iw];
/*     */     
/* 231 */     Vector dR = new Vector();
/* 232 */     Vector Nx = new Vector();
/* 233 */     Vector Ny = new Vector();
/* 239 */     while (flag.booleanValue())
/*     */     {
/* 244 */       temp = conv2(this.fillRegion, this.con);
/*     */       
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 249 */       this.gc.calculateGradient(this.sourceRegion, this.ih, this.iw);
/* 250 */       sourceGradX = this.gc.gradientX;
/* 251 */       sourceGradY = this.gc.gradientY;
/*     */       
/* 253 */       dR.clear();
/* 254 */       Nx.clear();
/* 255 */       Ny.clear();
/* 260 */       for (i = 0; i < temp[0].length; i++) {
/* 261 */         for (int j = 0; j < temp.length; j++) {
/* 262 */           if (temp[j][i] > 0.0D)
/*     */           {
/* 263 */             dR.add(Integer.valueOf(i * temp.length + j));
/* 264 */             Nx.add(Double.valueOf(sourceGradX[j][i]));
/* 265 */             Ny.add(Double.valueOf(sourceGradY[j][i]));
/*     */           }
/*     */         }
/*     */       }
/* 270 */       double[][] N = normr(Nx, Ny);
/*     */       
/* 272 */       Vector q = new Vector();
/* 273 */       double count = 0.0D;
/* 278 */       for (i = 0; i < dR.size(); i++)
/*     */       {
/* 279 */         int[][] Hp = getpatch(this.pixelmap, ((Integer)dR.get(i)).intValue());
/* 280 */         for (int j = 0; j < Hp.length; j++) {
/* 281 */           for (int k = 0; k < Hp[0].length; k++)
/*     */           {
/* 282 */             int col = Hp[j][k] / this.ih;
/* 283 */             int row = Hp[j][k] % this.ih;
/* 284 */             if (this.fillRegion[row][col] == 0.0D)
/*     */             {
/* 285 */               count += this.confidence[row][col];
/* 286 */               q.add(Integer.valueOf(Hp[j][k]));
/*     */             }
/*     */           }
/*     */         }
/* 291 */         int col = ((Integer)dR.get(i)).intValue() / this.ih;
/* 292 */         int row = ((Integer)dR.get(i)).intValue() % this.ih;
/* 293 */         this.confidence[row][col] = (count / (Hp.length * Hp[0].length));
/* 294 */         count = 0.0D;
/*     */       }
/* 297 */       double maxPriority = 0.0D;
/* 298 */       int maxPriorityIndex = -1;
/* 303 */       for (i = 0; i < dR.size(); i++)
/*     */       {
/* 304 */         int col = ((Integer)dR.get(i)).intValue() / this.ih;
/* 305 */         int row = ((Integer)dR.get(i)).intValue() % this.ih;
/*     */         
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 310 */         this.data[row][col] = (Math.abs(this.gradientX[row][col] * N[i][0] + this.gradientY[row][col] * N[i][1]) + 0.001D);
/*     */         
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 315 */         double Rcp = (1.0D - this.omega) * this.confidence[row][col] + this.omega;
/*     */         
/* 317 */         double tempPriority = this.Alpha * Rcp + this.Beta * this.data[row][col];
/* 322 */         if (tempPriority >= maxPriority)
/*     */         {
/* 323 */           maxPriority = tempPriority;
/* 324 */           maxPriorityIndex = i;
/*     */         }
/*     */       }
/* 328 */       if (maxPriorityIndex == -1) {
/*     */         break;
/*     */       }
/* 336 */       int[][] Hp = getpatch(this.pixelmap, ((Integer)dR.get(maxPriorityIndex)).intValue());
/* 337 */       double[][] toFill = new double[Hp.length][Hp[0].length];
/* 338 */       double[][] toFillTrans = new double[Hp[0].length][Hp.length];
/* 343 */       for (i = 0; i < Hp.length; i++) {
/* 344 */         for (int j = 0; j < Hp[0].length; j++)
/*     */         {
/* 345 */           int col = Hp[i][j] / this.ih;
/* 346 */           int row = Hp[i][j] % this.ih;
/* 347 */           toFill[i][j] = this.fillRegion[row][col];
/* 348 */           toFillTrans[j][i] = this.fillRegion[row][col];
/*     */         }
/*     */       }
/* 352 */       this.pixelPosX = (((Integer)dR.get(maxPriorityIndex)).intValue() / this.ih);
/* 353 */       this.pixelPosY = (((Integer)dR.get(maxPriorityIndex)).intValue() % this.ih);
/*     */       
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 358 */       int[] best = bestExemplar(Hp, toFillTrans, this.initialSourceRegion, quickInpaint);
/*     */       
/* 360 */       int nRows = best[3] - best[2] + 1;
/* 361 */       int nCols = best[1] - best[0] + 1;
/*     */       
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 366 */       int[][] X = new int[nRows][nCols];
/* 367 */       int[][] Y = new int[nRows][nCols];
/* 368 */       int[][] Hq = new int[nRows][nCols];
/* 369 */       for (i = 0; i < nRows; i++) {
/* 370 */         for (int j = 0; j < nCols; j++)
/*     */         {
/* 371 */           X[i][j] = (best[0] + j);
/* 372 */           Y[i][j] = (best[2] + i);
/* 373 */           X[i][j] += Y[i][j] * this.ih;
/*     */         }
/*     */       }
/* 377 */       int p = ((Integer)dR.get(maxPriorityIndex)).intValue();
/* 382 */       for (i = 0; i < toFill.length; i++) {
/* 383 */         for (int j = 0; j < toFill[0].length; j++) {
/* 384 */           if (toFill[i][j] != 0.0D)
/*     */           {
/* 385 */             toFill[i][j] = 1.0D;
/* 386 */             int col = Hp[i][j] / this.ih;
/* 387 */             int row = Hp[i][j] % this.ih;
/*     */             
/* 389 */             int col1 = Hq[i][j] / this.ih;
/* 390 */             int row1 = Hq[i][j] % this.ih;
/*     */             
/* 392 */             this.fillRegion[row][col] = 0.0D;
/* 393 */             this.sourceRegion[row][col] = 1;
/*     */             
/*     */ 
/* 396 */             this.confidence[row][col] = this.confidence[(p % this.ih)][(p / this.ih)];
/* 397 */             this.gradientX[row][col] = this.gradientX[row1][col1];
/* 398 */             this.gradientY[row][col] = this.gradientY[row1][col1];
/* 399 */             this.pixelmap[row][col] = this.pixelmap[row1][col1];
/*     */             
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 404 */             int[] color = new int[3];
/* 405 */             color[0] = (0xFF & this.pixelmap[row1][col1] >> 16);
/* 406 */             color[1] = (0xFF & this.pixelmap[row1][col1] >> 8);
/* 407 */             color[2] = (0xFF & this.pixelmap[row1][col1]);
/* 408 */             this.raster.setPixel(col, row, color);
/*     */           }
/*     */         }
/*     */       }
/* 413 */       if (this.halt.booleanValue()) {
/*     */         break;
/*     */       }
/* 414 */       this.owner.updateStats(this.origImg);
/* 415 */       Thread.yield();
/*     */       
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 420 */       flag = Boolean.valueOf(false);
/* 421 */       for (i = 0; i < this.fillRegion.length; i++)
/*     */       {
/* 422 */         for (int j = 0; j < this.fillRegion[0].length; j++) {
/* 423 */           if (this.fillRegion[i][j] == 1.0D)
/*     */           {
/* 424 */             flag = Boolean.valueOf(true);
/* 425 */             break;
/*     */           }
/*     */         }
/* 428 */         if (flag.booleanValue()) {
/*     */           break;
/*     */         }
/*     */       }
/* 431 */       if (this.halt.booleanValue()) {
/*     */         break;
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/* 437 */     this.gc = null;
/* 438 */     if (!this.halt.booleanValue()) {
/* 439 */       this.completed = Boolean.valueOf(true);
/*     */     } else {
/* 441 */       this.completed = Boolean.valueOf(false);
/*     */     }
/* 443 */     this.owner.updateStats(this.origImg);
/* 444 */     Thread.yield();
/*     */   }
/*     */   
/*     */   void initialize_confidence_term()
/*     */   {
/* 452 */     this.confidence = new double[this.ih][this.iw];
/* 453 */     for (int i = 0; i < this.ih; i++) {
/* 454 */       for (int j = 0; j < this.iw; j++)
/*     */       {
/* 455 */         int p = this.pixelmap[i][j];
/* 456 */         int r = 0xFF & p >> 16;
/* 457 */         int g = 0xFF & p >> 8;
/* 458 */         int b = 0xFF & p;
/* 459 */         if ((r == 0) && (g == 255) && (b == 0)) {
/* 460 */           this.confidence[i][j] = 0.0D;
/*     */         } else {
/* 462 */           this.confidence[i][j] = 1.0D;
/*     */         }
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/*     */   }
/*     */   
/*     */   void initialize_data_term()
/*     */   {
/* 473 */     this.data = new double[this.ih][this.iw];
/* 474 */     for (int i = 0; i < this.ih; i++) {
/* 475 */       for (int j = 0; j < this.iw; j++) {
/* 476 */         this.data[i][j] = -0.1D;
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/*     */   }
/*     */   
/*     */   double[][] conv2(double[][] a, double[][] b)
/*     */   {
/* 489 */     int ra = a.length;
/* 490 */     int ca = a[0].length;
/* 491 */     int rb = b.length;
/* 492 */     int cb = b[0].length;
/*     */     
/*     */ 
/* 495 */     double[][] c = new double[ra + rb - 1][ca + cb - 1];
/* 496 */     for (int i = 0; i < rb; i++) {
/* 497 */       for (int j = 0; j < cb; j++)
/*     */       {
/* 498 */         int r1 = i;
/* 499 */         int r2 = r1 + ra - 1;
/* 500 */         int c1 = j;
/* 501 */         int c2 = c1 + ca - 1;
/* 502 */         for (int k = r1; k < r2; k++) {
/* 503 */           for (int l = c1; l < c2; l++) {
/* 504 */             c[k][l] += b[i][j] * a[(k - r1 + 1)][(l - c1 + 1)];
/*     */           }
/*     */         }
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/* 510 */     double[][] out = new double[ra][ca];
/*     */     
/* 512 */     int r1 = rb / 2;
/* 513 */     int r2 = r1 + ra - 1;
/* 514 */     int c1 = cb / 2;
/* 515 */     int c2 = c1 + ca - 1;
/* 516 */     for (int i = r1; i < r2; i++) {
/* 517 */       for (int j = c1; j < c2; j++) {
/* 518 */         out[(i - r1 + 1)][(j - c1 + 1)] = c[i][j];
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/* 521 */     return out;
/*     */   }
/*     */   
/*     */   double[][] normr(Vector X, Vector Y)
/*     */   {
/* 533 */     double[][] normalized = new double[X.size()][2];
/* 534 */     for (int i = 0; i < X.size(); i++)
/*     */     {
/* 535 */       double temp1 = ((Double)X.get(i)).doubleValue();
/* 536 */       double temp2 = ((Double)Y.get(i)).doubleValue();
/*     */       
/* 538 */       temp1 *= temp1;
/* 539 */       temp2 *= temp2;
/*     */       double temp3;
/*     */       double temp3;
/* 543 */       if (temp1 + temp2 == 0.0D)
/*     */       {
/* 544 */         temp3 = 0.0D;
/*     */       }
/*     */       else
/*     */       {
/* 546 */         temp3 = 1.0D / (temp1 + temp2);
/* 547 */         temp3 = Math.sqrt(temp3);
/*     */       }
/* 550 */       normalized[i][0] = (temp3 * ((Double)X.get(i)).doubleValue());
/* 551 */       normalized[i][1] = (temp3 * ((Double)Y.get(i)).doubleValue());
/*     */     }
/* 554 */     return normalized;
/*     */   }
/*     */   
/*     */   int[][] getpatch(int[][] pixelmap, int p)
/*     */   {
/* 570 */     p -= 1;
/* 571 */     int y = p / this.ih;
/* 572 */     p %= this.ih;
/* 573 */     int x = p + 1;
/*     */     
/* 575 */     int temp1 = Math.max(x - this.w, 0);
/* 576 */     int temp2 = Math.min(x + this.w, this.ih - 1);
/* 577 */     int temp3 = Math.max(y - this.w, 0);
/* 578 */     int temp4 = Math.min(y + this.w, this.iw - 1);
/*     */     
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 582 */     int[][] N = new int[temp4 - temp3 + 1][temp2 - temp1 + 1];
/* 584 */     for (int i = 0; i < temp4 - temp3 + 1; i++) {
/* 585 */       for (int j = 0; j < temp2 - temp1 + 1; j++) {
/* 588 */         N[i][j] = (temp1 + j + (temp3 + i) * this.ih);
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/* 591 */     return N;
/*     */   }
/*     */   
/*     */   int[] bestExemplar(int[][] Hp, double[][] toFill, int[][] sourceRegion, Boolean quickInpaint)
/*     */   {
/* 606 */     int[][] Ip = new int[toFill.length][toFill[0].length];
/* 607 */     for (int i = 0; i < toFill[0].length; i++) {
/* 608 */       for (int j = 0; j < toFill.length; j++)
/*     */       {
/* 609 */         int col = Hp[i][j] / this.ih;
/* 610 */         int row = Hp[i][j] % this.ih;
/* 611 */         Ip[j][i] = this.pixelmap[row][col];
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/* 615 */     int[][] rIp = new int[Ip.length][Ip[0].length];
/* 616 */     int[][] gIp = new int[Ip.length][Ip[0].length];
/* 617 */     int[][] bIp = new int[Ip.length][Ip[0].length];
/* 619 */     for (int i = 0; i < Ip.length; i++) {
/* 620 */       for (int j = 0; j < Ip[0].length; j++)
/*     */       {
/* 624 */         rIp[i][j] = (0xFF & Ip[i][j] >> 16);
/* 625 */         gIp[i][j] = (0xFF & Ip[i][j] >> 8);
/* 626 */         bIp[i][j] = (0xFF & Ip[i][j]);
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/* 635 */     int m = Ip.length;
/* 636 */     int n = Ip[0].length;
/*     */     int nn;
/*     */     int mm;
/*     */     int nn;
/*     */     int startX;
/*     */     int startY;
/*     */     int endX;
/* 637 */     if (quickInpaint.booleanValue())
/*     */     {
/* 639 */       int startX = Math.max(0, this.pixelPosX - n / 2 - this.continuousRow - 25);
/* 640 */       int startY = Math.max(0, this.pixelPosY - m / 2 - this.continuousCol - 15);
/* 641 */       int endX = Math.min(this.pixelmap[0].length - 1, this.pixelPosX + n / 2 + this.continuousRow + 25);
/* 642 */       int endY = Math.min(this.pixelmap.length - 1, this.pixelPosY + m / 2 + this.continuousCol + 15);
/* 643 */       int mm = endY - startY + 1;
/* 644 */       nn = endX - startX + 1;
/*     */     }
/*     */     else
/*     */     {
/* 646 */       mm = this.pixelmap.length;
/* 647 */       nn = this.pixelmap[0].length;
/* 648 */       startX = 0;
/* 649 */       startY = 0;
/*     */       int endY;
/* 650 */       endX = endY = 0;
/*     */     }
/* 653 */     double patchErr = 0.0D;double err = 0.0D;double bestErr = 1.0E+020D;double bestPatchErr1 = 1.0E+020D;
/* 654 */     int[] best = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
/* 655 */     Boolean skipPatchFlag = Boolean.valueOf(false);
/*     */     
/*     */ 
/* 658 */     int N = startX + nn - n + 1;int M = startY + mm - m + 1;
/* 659 */     for (int j = startX; j < N; j++)
/*     */     {
/* 660 */       int J = j + n - 1;
/* 661 */       for (int i = startY; i < M; i++)
/*     */       {
/* 662 */         int I = i + m - 1;
/*     */         
/* 664 */         skipPatchFlag = Boolean.valueOf(false);
/*     */         
/* 666 */         double meanR = 0.0D;
/* 667 */         double meanG = 0.0D;
/* 668 */         double meanB = 0.0D;
/*     */         
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 674 */         int jj = j;
/* 674 */         for (int jj2 = 0; jj <= J; jj2++)
/*     */         {
/* 675 */           int ii = i;
/* 675 */           for (int ii2 = 0; ii <= I; ii2++)
/*     */           {
/* 680 */             if (sourceRegion[ii][jj] != 1)
/*     */             {
/* 681 */               skipPatchFlag = Boolean.valueOf(true);
/* 682 */               break;
/*     */             }
/* 684 */             if (toFill[ii2][jj2] == 0.0D)
/*     */             {
/* 685 */               int rImage = 0xFF & this.pixelmap[ii][jj] >> 16;
/* 686 */               int gImage = 0xFF & this.pixelmap[ii][jj] >> 8;
/* 687 */               int bImage = 0xFF & this.pixelmap[ii][jj];
/*     */               
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 692 */               err = rImage - rIp[ii2][jj2];patchErr += err * err;
/* 693 */               err = gImage - gIp[ii2][jj2];patchErr += err * err;
/* 694 */               err = bImage - bIp[ii2][jj2];patchErr += err * err;
/*     */               
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 698 */               meanR += rImage;
/* 699 */               meanG += gImage;
/* 700 */               meanB += bImage;
/*     */             }
/* 675 */             ii++;
/*     */           }
/* 703 */           if (skipPatchFlag.booleanValue()) {
/*     */             break;
/*     */           }
/* 674 */           jj++;
/*     */         }
/* 711 */         if ((!skipPatchFlag.booleanValue()) && (patchErr < bestErr))
/*     */         {
/* 712 */           bestErr = patchErr;
/* 713 */           best[0] = i;best[1] = I;
/* 714 */           best[2] = j;best[3] = J;
/*     */           
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/*     */ 
/* 719 */           double patchErr1 = 0.0D;
/* 720 */           jj = j;
/* 720 */           for (jj2 = 0; jj <= J; jj2++)
/*     */           {
/* 721 */             int ii = i;
/* 721 */             for (int ii2 = 0; ii <= I; ii2++)
/*     */             {
/* 722 */               if (toFill[ii2][jj2] == 1.0D)
/*     */               {
/* 723 */                 int rImage = 0xFF & this.pixelmap[ii][jj] >> 16;
/* 724 */                 int gImage = 0xFF & this.pixelmap[ii][jj] >> 8;
/* 725 */                 int bImage = 0xFF & this.pixelmap[ii][jj];
/*     */                 
/* 727 */                 err = rImage - meanR;patchErr1 += err * err;
/* 728 */                 err = gImage - meanG;patchErr1 += err * err;
/* 729 */                 err = bImage - meanB;patchErr1 += err * err;
/*     */               }
/* 721 */               ii++;
/*     */             }
/* 720 */             jj++;
/*     */           }
/* 733 */           bestPatchErr1 = patchErr1;
/*     */         }
/* 734 */         else if ((!skipPatchFlag.booleanValue()) && (patchErr == bestErr))
/*     */         {
/* 740 */           double patchErr1 = 0.0D;
/* 741 */           jj = j;
/* 741 */           for (jj2 = 0; jj <= J; jj2++)
/*     */           {
/* 742 */             int ii = i;
/* 742 */             for (int ii2 = 0; ii <= I; ii2++)
/*     */             {
/* 743 */               if (toFill[ii2][jj2] == 1.0D)
/*     */               {
/* 744 */                 int rImage = 0xFF & this.pixelmap[ii][jj] >> 16;
/* 745 */                 int gImage = 0xFF & this.pixelmap[ii][jj] >> 8;
/* 746 */                 int bImage = 0xFF & this.pixelmap[ii][jj];
/*     */                 
/* 748 */                 err = rImage - meanR;patchErr1 += err * err;
/* 749 */                 err = gImage - meanG;patchErr1 += err * err;
/* 750 */                 err = bImage - meanB;patchErr1 += err * err;
/*     */               }
/* 742 */               ii++;
/*     */             }
/* 741 */             jj++;
/*     */           }
/* 758 */           if (bestPatchErr1 > patchErr1)
/*     */           {
/* 759 */             best[0] = i;best[1] = I;
/* 760 */             best[2] = j;best[3] = J;
/* 761 */             bestPatchErr1 = patchErr1;
/*     */           }
/*     */         }
/* 765 */         patchErr = 0.0D;
/*     */       }
/*     */     }
/* 769 */     if ((best[0] == 0) && (best[1] == 0) && (best[2] == 0) && (best[3] == 0)) {
/* 770 */       return bestExemplar(Hp, toFill, sourceRegion, Boolean.valueOf(false));
/*     */     }
/* 772 */     return best;
/*     */   }
/*     */ }
```

This code runs as .exe file where the user selects the region to be inpainted and the algorithm is applied to the selected region which turns green as the user selects. I have made android project to select the region and turn it to green. Now next I want to use this green area to get inpainted. Please discuss with me possible methods. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have 1 vote for editing great

Comment: thanks! Now can you please help me out!

Comment: yeah sure can you draw picture and show so i understand wisly about your requirementd

Comment: look at this link to understand better. https://github.com/sapandiwakar/Image-Inapainting/blob/master/src/inpaint/ImageInpaint.java

Comment: may i ask you for what purpose you use this type of code?

Comment: for intelligent object removal. you just have to select an image region and it will disappear retaining the background. It will look as if the object was never there.

Comment: Hi...I am also developing the same idea.do u find any soln